# How to get image CID values without cid: from <img src= using regex?

Tags: regex, image, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Here my scenario I want to get the cid value without cid: from the img src in mail content. I've the inline image code like `<img src="cid:ii_k4ib6vux0" alt="image.png" width="195" height="162">`.

Now I want to get the cid value `ii_k4ib6vux0`. When I try to use the regex `cid([^""']+)` I've got the value with cid like `cid:ii_k4ib6vux0`. But I want to get the value only. Please guide me to get the exact values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you using? Your regex is capturing the `cid` part, so of course it will be part of the results. In your case, you should just grab the first group (what's between parenthesis). You should also include the colon.

Comment: Were you able to solve it, CSK? You should mark an answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
<cfset aString = '<img src="cid:ii_k4ib6vux0" alt="image.png" width="195" height="162">' />

<cfset aMatch = REMatch('"cid:([^"]*)"', aString) />
<cfdump var="#replace(aMatch[1], "cid:", "")#" />
```

---

**Example:**

https://trycf.com/gist/9202b3dd2cca2cf0341a594dc007644f/acf2016?theme=monokai

---

**Update:**

Using REFind

```
<cfset aString = '<img src="cid:ii_k4ib6vux0" alt="image.png" width="195" height="162">' />

<cfset aMatch = REFind('"cid:([^"]*)"',aString,1,true,"ALL") />
<cfdump var="#aMatch[1].match[2]#" />
```

https://trycf.com/gist/809a30fdc16cc6deac6d1034dfb8adc2/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Alex, thanks for your answer. Is there any regex value to get the exact value without replace empty values for `cid:` ?

Comment: I would remove the extra quotes (apparently they don't do anything) and also include the single quote, just in case: `REFind('cid:([^"'']*)',...`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture only that code and not having to check the groups (parts between parenthesis), you can use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=cid:)[^"']+
```

This will match any character besides `'` and `"` which come after `cid:`.

Otherwise, using a regex similar to yours (note the `:` and the removed `"`):

```
cid:([^"']+)
```

You need to check the first group. Depending on what language you are using, the first group may be the whole captured string and you may need to check the second group.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer. I've tried the above code its throwing like `sequence ( ...) not recognized` error. I'm using regex in coldfusion language with ReMatch() function.

Comment: Well, that error must be related to how you are using these in Coldfusion (apparently it doesn't support lookbehinds). If you validate these regular expressions, they work just fine. Regarding Alex' answer, beware it's not considering `'`. This will matter if you don't always get attributes between `"`. You will need to double the `'` for it to work (that escapes the quote).

Comment: @Andrew thanks, you're correct. To make it work with either double or single quotes would be CSK's homework.

Comment: I mentioned that because the single quote was already present in CSK's original regex. :)